# require js is not loading the modules from the configs

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have the `index.html` as:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
       <script data-main="scripts/main" src="lib/require.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Example 1: basic usage</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the `main.js`:

```
requirejs.config({
    waitSeconds: 200,
    paths: {
        "app": "app"
    }
});
```

and the `app.js`:

```
define(function () {
    alert('Hello World');
});
```

both `main` and `app` are under `scripts` folder.

When I opened the `index.html`, and in the console if I give:

```
require("app")
```

I get an error like this:

```
Uncaught Error: Module name "app" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
```

Not sure, where I have made mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't started your app, to do this you should call requirejs(['app/app']).
Here is the basic requirejs example https://github.com/volojs/create-template/tree/master/www